# Rails has_one relation not working, but only inside Heroku worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

`We have the following has_one association:

```
class InspectionSettings < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :inspection_evaluation_lights, dependent: :destroy
end


class InspectionEvaluationLights < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inspection_settings
end
```

Both model names are not inflected, which is noted in `inflections.rb`.

It all works as expected, ActiveRecord methods like `InspectionSettings.find(xy).inspection_evaluation_lights` return the object one would expect.

Except when run inside a Heroku worker instance, where it throws an `undefined method inspection_evaluation_lights for InspectionSettings class`error.

I've tried all kinds of workarounds like specifying a `class_name` or `inverse_of` for both relations, but to no avail.

Strangest bug I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was the inclusion of an ActiveSupport::Concern in the `InspectionSettings' model.

Why this problem only occurs when the ActiveRecord method is called inside a Heroku worker is still beyond me.